# how to append to a file on particular position using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I have a file and I want to append data to particular position on it.

I went through http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_filename_data_options_callback but I couldn't found to append data on specific position in file.

So any help would be appreciated.Thank you.!!

Comment: you want to write the file. http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refer this [**`link`**](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writesync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position)

Using this you can write to a specific position in a file.

**Code snippet:**

```
var position = 5;
var file_path = 'file.txt';
var new_text = 'abcde';

fs.readFile(file_path, function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    var file_content = data.toString();
    file_content = file_content.substring(position);
    var file = fs.openSync(file_path,'r+');
    var bufferedText = new Buffer(new_text+file_content);
    fs.writeSync(file, bufferedText, 0, bufferedText.length, position);
    fs.close(file);
});
```

The **file.txt** should be on the same path.

**file.txt** already contains this text: **OldText**

**Output:** The new text will be **OldTe`abcde`xt** i.e, OldTeabcdext

Comment: thank you..but this code is overriding text in a file..I want to write in between as you displayed as output in your answer.

Comment: Did you manually created this file (**file.txt**) with the text **OldText**, And then run this code ??

Comment: Yes,I created it manually,and here is output of that code "OldTeabcde".I have used same code which you have provided in your answer.

Comment: @Divyesh I have updated the code and is now checked and working.

Comment: if anyone receives `throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK();` error, use call back function for fs.close() as below 
`fs.close(file, (err) => {
      if (err)
        console.error('Failed to close file', err);
      else {
        console.log("\n> File Closed successfully");
      }
    });`