# JS/Node: Updating a JSON file with the square brackets

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

My application needs to write the new users who sign up in to a JSON file, so that later I send this file to users.

What I want is something like:

```
[
 {"username": "A"},
 {"username": "B"},
 {"username": "C"}
]
```

When a new user "D" signs up, NodeJS will update the file as:

```
[
 {"username": "A"},
 {"username": "B"},
 {"username": "C"},
 {"username": "D"}
]
```

However I'm having problems to implement this because although I can 'append' to the file, I cannot write a user name just before the closing ']'.

I tried to do without square brackets and JSON.parse(arayFromFileRead) but it gives me an

> 'unexpected token {'

error.

Could somebody help with either:

1. Writing to the file, one line before the last line. That is, the line before the closing squire bracket.
2. Reading a file as a JSON object without the enclosing square brackets.

Thank you.

Comment: Check https://github.com/jprichardson/node-jsonfile

Answer (score 2):

In order to write proper JSON (and be able to parse it as such with `JSON.parse`), you need to have commas between objects inside an array.

```
[
 {"username": "A"},
 {"username": "B"},
 {"username": "C"}
]
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right. But still my problem remains. JSON.parse will not work without square brackets.

Comment: So you want to be able to edit the file every time a new user signs up? Sounds inefficient. Have you thought about having multiple JSON files, one per each user, and then parse them all to create one JSON file when sending?

Comment: Hi. Do you think that would be efficient? Because I expect this file to be accessed more than new users signing up. If I create a new file for each user sign up, then I need to read them all and parse them all each time I need the list of user names.

Comment: Why don't you use a database? Other option (rather unefficient): why don't you parse JSON, add an element to the array, and stringify it again entirely into the file? Otherwise, you can still [write into a file at a specific position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352389/how-to-append-to-a-file-on-particular-position-using-node-js).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this example:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function addUser(user, callback) {
    var usersFile = './users.json';

    fs.readFile(usersFile, function(err, users) {
      if (err) {
        return (callback)? callback(err) : console.error(err);
      }

      users = (users)? JSON.parse(users) : [];
      users.push(user);
      fs.writeFile(usersFile, JSON.stringify(users), function(err, result){
        (callback)? callback(err, result) : console.error(err);
      });
    });
}

addUser({username: 'D', password: 'blablabla'});
```

**logic**:

to have one users.json file where we'll keep all user data serialized by `JSON.stringify()` function.

to do so You've to read whole file to variable, parse it, push new record to variable, serialize (stringify) and save it back to file

**benefits**:

there is no benefit! when Your file will be bigger You'll waste more memory and CPU to read it, push, serialize, write back. also Your file will be locked during read/write

**SO BETTER TO DO THIS:**

1) create **users** folder

2) make Your code like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var md5 = require('md5');
var usersDir = './users';

function addUser(user, callback) {
    var userFile = path.join(usersDir, md5(user.username)+'.json');

    fs.writeFile(userFile, JSON.stringify(user), function(err, result){
      (callback)? callback(err, result) : console.error(err);
    });
}

addUser({username: 'D', password: 'blablabla'});
```

**logic**: You have users folder where You keep users records "file per user" way

**benefits**:

when You've 1 file (users.json) You're having issue of parallel accessing same file.

but when You files are separate, so filesystem itself acts as database, where json file is row and content is document.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful if you'd also give a high level explanation of your solution.

Comment: Thank you num8er. I have my user data in Mongo objects. The reason I need this file of just the user names is to pass to an autocomplete routine. In the client side, users can send messages to other users, and this list will be used to autocomplete the username in browser. So whenever a new user signs up, I will create a Mongo document, but at the same time write the new username in to this file. That way the app can easily send this list for the browser.

Comment: @FelixKling thank You for Your comment. appreciate. I've put explanation after code example.

Comment: @madu just make an api and do request and get only usernames. You're trying to optimize "nothing". There is no logic to make it so for autocomplete. Even so, better just have file where You comma separate usernames: "num8er, madu, felix"  and do just: usernames = data.split(',')   isn't it flexible? (: