# How to append a code snippet to HTML using node fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I want to add a code snippet to an html file using the node fs command line tool.
I saw this solution [how to append to a file on particular position using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352389/how-to-append-to-a-file-on-particular-position-using-node-js)  but it uses the position for appending to a file.

I have this html snippet

```
<html><body><h1>hello world</body></html>
```

I want to append

```
<script>console.log('hello world')</script>
```

before the closing body tag. 
I want the output to be like this

```
<html><body><h1>hello world</h1><script>console.log('hello world')</script></body></html>
```

Comment: is the question about finding the right position?

Comment: yes it is, i want too append the javascript right before the closing body tag

Answer (score 4):

Why not use Regex?

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('./test.html', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var toPrepand = "<script>console.log('hello world')</script>";
  data = data.replace(/\<\/body>/g, toPrepand + '</body>');
  console.log(data);
});
```

You won't have to think about where to place - because you already say - right before the `</body>` tag.

After that simply write the new data to that HTML file.

If you also want to know how to write your file directly afterward:

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('./test.html', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  var toPrepand = "<script>console.log('hello world')</script>";
  var result = data.replace(/\<\/body>/g, toPrepand + '</body>');

  fs.writeFile('./test.html', result, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

There are many options to do so - find the position or use a [HTML parser](https://www.google.at/search?q=node%20js%20dom&oq=node%20js%20dom&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3287j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or simply string replace that string.

Comment: nice and clean, awesome

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple string operations to achieve this:

```
var initialString = '<html><body><h1>hello world</body></html>';
var insert = '<script>console.log("hello world")</script>';
```

then find the position using indexOf:

`var pos = initialString.indexOf('</body>');`

slice and concat the strings:

`var output = [initialString.slice(0, pos), insert, initialString.slice(pos)].join('')`

And use output of course :-)

If you want something more scalable you could also have a look at any HTML parser / virtual DOM implementation for Node (like jsdom https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use the 'cheerio' node package to do it.
https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

that is really useful and just like using jQuery.